# How to show a node of a content type in two different places with different url and hiding some fields in the one place in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have a content type named Ailment, which displays all the ailments of the particular user, when u click the ailment, it goes to a particular node, displaying details and graphs of that ailment which is added by the user, this is fine.

Now in another page I wan to search ailment of the whole site and display the ailments, and when they click the ailment it should show the graphs and should hide some fields which shows only for the particular user..

For ex: user A is having a page where ailments wil be listed, when he clicks the ailment, for example cancer, then it goes to myailment/cancer, where some fields and graphs wil be displaying.. this is fine

Now I am having a another page /topailment, where I have a search box, any user can come and search any ailment, it should display the ailment for example cancer, then it should go to the page, topailment/cancer, where it should display only graphs and hide fields..

Hope I am clear..

I am trying to find a solution but going no where...

Please help

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is possible with Page Manager.  It will take some learning, but the best place to start is here:

http://nodeone.se/en/learn-page-manager-part-1-overview

Essentially, you want a node to have two different page displays.  There are several ways to do this, but page manager is the most direct for me.

Good luck!

Mike

Comment: Can you please suggest how to do it step by step, i saw that video which you mentioned but i dont know how it wil be helping me..

Answer (score 0):

As is always the case in Drupal, there are many ways you could do this. Two options come to mind immediately:

1. Use views and **create a view with multiple displays** to renders your Ailment nodes in different ways.
2. **Create custom display modes** using the [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) module.

You could even go for a blend of both options by creating additional display modes with Display Suite and rendering those display modes with views.

To do it purely with Display Suite: once display modes are configured, you can enable the 'View mode per node' option made available by Display Suite Extras (bundled with the core module) and pass the view mode as a URL parameter to the node. This way you would link to your node as normal from most pages and from the user page you would link to (for example) `node/123?v=personalized` to use the personalized display mode.

Which of these approaches you go for probably depends on your familiarity with these modules and what you're already using.

Comment: the nodes in ailment that is for example cancer, having a url as myailment/cancer, now by creating a page view i can list all these nodes in for ex: /topailment page, but when i click the ailment tat is cancer in topailment page, it goes to the myailment/cancer... i want it to be topailment/cancer when i search in the whole site for the ailment.and it for a particular user it is myailment/cancer which is already there..

Answer (score -1):

There is a module for that :) . It solves this specific problem and plays very nicely with display suite for hiding modules. You have to create a new view mode, assign it to your content type, select which fields you want to hide for each view mode and then you create a URL in your manage fields section for that particular view mode. https://www.drupal.org/project/view_mode_page